# Kotlin abstract class must have constructor and get initialized

Tags: kotlin

When I have this class hierarchy:

## SUPERCLASS

```
abstract class AbsSuperClass {
    abstract fun someFun()
}
```

## SUBCLASS

```
class Subclass : AbsSuperClass {
    override fun someFun()
}
```

I get an IDE error in the subclass saying:

> This type has a constructor, and thus must be initialized here

But doesnt this counter the whole argument of having abstract classes? I just DONT want the abstract class to be initialized

Answer (score 2):

You have just forgotten `()` in your class extension:

```
class Subclass : AbsSuperClass() {
    override fun someFun()
}
```

Comment: Yes this will make the code work, but why should I initialize an abstract superclass?
That doesnt make sense and voids the name "abstract"

Comment: don't worry, if a component is a class in Kotlin it should have the brackets, otherwise use an interface.

Comment: Abstract classes are still classes and might have initialization code. A subclass must always call through to the superclass’s constructor to ensure initialization occurs.  You can’t instantiate an abstract class but it still represents class behavior.

Comment: Okay. This is somehow counter intuitive. isnt it?

Comment: It makes sense to me.  After all, there's no point in writing an abstract class unless you expect it to have a concrete subclass (or sub-subclass…).  And if that concrete subclass gets instantiated, how will the abstract superclass set itself up?  (It could have private stuff that needs setting up, that its subclasses won't see.)  Abstract classes can have quite a lot of state and behaviour, even though they need subclasses to specify some more.  (In this case it's simple enough it could be an interface, which of course has no constructor; but most cases aren't so simple!)

Comment: Think about why you would choose to use an abstract class instead of an interface. Usually, it would be because you need to set up properties that carry state. For them to be set up, they have to be initialized. In your example, the abstract class carries no state. It might as well be an interface, and then you don't need to call a constructor.